# Code logging undefined when ran in a $.get request, but when ran on the page it works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is logging undefined when I run it, but when I run it on the current page (removing the `$.get` request, and the `$(f)`

This is my code:

```
var product = 20219291;
function check(id) {
    $.get('http://m.roblox.com/items/'+id+'/privatesales').success(function(r) {
        var d = r.replace(/img/gi,"flip");
        var f = $(d).find(".ui-btn-text a").first().attr('href');
        console.log(f);
        var s = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('&expectedPrice'));
        var userAssetId = s.replace('/Catalog/VerifyTransfer?userAssetOptionId=', '')
        var price = link.substring(link.indexOf("&expectedPrice=") + "&expectedPrice=".length);
        console.log(userAssetId, price);
    });
}
check(161211433);
```

Comment: Could you paste the return value of "r" from the ajax?

Answer (score 0):

When you access this page via the browser, you are logged in, so there is an active session.

When you try to access the page with ajax, the return html is the content of this page I suppose :
 https://m.roblox.com/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fitems%2f161211433%2fprivatesales

If you need to login to access some content, I suggest you use the api from server side :

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=User-created_web_APIs